# Problems with styling Nextjs & tailwind

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make my navbar change color on scroll, I cannot get the colors to register inside ('').
It's just staying as ffffff.
Is this some tailwind issue?

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const colorChange = () => {
            if (window.scrollY >= 90) {
                setColor('#ffffff');
            }
        };
    });
```

I tried to reinstall some dependancies and really looked over the code several times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use dependency array in your `useEffect` hook, and also should add the `addEventListener()` method.

Replace your code with this one:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const colorChange = () => {
      if (window.scrollY >= 90) {
        setColor('#ffffff');
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener('scroll', colorChange)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', colorChange)
}, []);
```

Don't forget to import the hooks:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
```

**Further readings:**

- [useEffect hook](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#parameters)
- [addEventListener() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp)
- [facebook/react#14920](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920)